# Dynamic IF statement

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to build a dynamic if statement in Excel VBA?  Basically I am trying to create a parametised calculation where the user will be able to enter the different variables i.e.

variable 1 "variable 2" "variable 3"

In this case 
variable 1 is a cell reference
variable 2 would be = or < or > etc
variable 2 would be a cell reference

Thus my If statement statement would be
 If variable1 varaible2 variable3 then "y" else "n"

When I try it in code

```
 If FinalvaluesArray(ArrayRow, 5) & SRCBook.Sheets("Filter Parameters").Cells(2, 4).Value & SRCBook.Sheets("Filter Parameters").Cells(2, 3).Value Then wbNew.Sheets("Output Table").Range(ResultString) = "Y" Else wbNew.Sheets("Output Table").Range(ResultString) = N"
```

It does not seem to evaluate the expression properly but always seems to return a true value.  is there anyway to buld such a function?

I tried bulding the expression up as a string first, and had the code like this:

```
EvaluateFunction = FinalvaluesArray(ArrayRow, 5) & SRCBook.Sheets("Filter Parameters").Cells(2, 4).Value & SRCBook.Sheets("Filter Parameters").Cells(2, 3).Value

If EvaluateFunction= true Then "Y" Else "N"
```

But that also did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trust the source from which your variables come, then you can simply do

```
If Application.Evaluate(FinalvaluesArray(ArrayRow, 5) & SRCBook.Sheets("Filter Parameters").Cells(2, 4).Value & SRCBook.Sheets("Filter Parameters").Cells(2, 3).Value) Then
    ....
End If
```

Otherwise this may run arbitrary code, so you might want to check that the values are numbers and/or operators before doing it.

Comment: +1, I had completely misunderstood the question. This is the right answer. The only alternative would be to create a function taking those three parameters and return true or false, but this is simpler.